# (not actual) Jenkins workspace missing dot files

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I have a setup of jenkins and git (gitlab). When jenkins pulls the repo in workspace it cuts down all dot files. How to avoid this? I've heard about option "override default ANT exclusions", but I can't find it =(

## UPD

not actual any more. problem was in zipping...

Comment: have you checked `.gitignore` for all missing files?

Comment: yes. it is not ignored by git..

Comment: Which OS is Jenkins running on? What command are you running to verify that the files are not there?

Comment: ubuntu 14. verifying with 'ls' (and by watching how deploy scripts fail =))

Comment: Check this - https://dotfiles.github.io

Comment: What kind of .files are you talking about? Is this a JS project? I know some of them have options to set the tracking of dotfiles on / off.

Comment: any dotfiles. this is no relative to project type, this is relative to jenkins pulling artifact to workspace

Comment: @ВладимирКорнилов Just to clarify: do you understand that when you execute `ls` it doesn't show dot files? You need to use `ls -a`.

Comment: @zaratustra Oooooh CRAP! You are right =((( Dotfiles are in place, I've used 'ls' instead of 'ls -A' and didn't see them in output. But they are really cutting during deploy and it seems that problem is with zipping. I use "cd $this->workspace && zip -q -r $targetZip * -x .git*" command and it seems to ignore all dotfiles... What a shame (

Comment: @ВладимирКорнилов I don't understand do you need to prepare a zip file with all the files in the directory?

Comment: @zaratustra I need to pack all files in workspace except git index to send it to target server. Already changed 'zip' to 'git archive', works like a charm. Thank you very much for pointing ti this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might misunderstand the `ls` command. Dot files are hidden files, you need to execute `ls -a` to see hidden files. There are plenty of ways to customize the output of this command.

Read more about the `ls` command [here](http://ss64.com/bash/ls.html)

Answer (score 1):

There was once a [bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13165) which led to lost dot-files when checking out the workspace. Probably you are running a faulty Jenkins-version (prior 1.509.2)?

Comment: Hmm - if you do not use any additional behaviors or steps which clean the workspace, i can't help you any further without the whole description of your job-configuration.

Comment: job is damn simple: get code from git, inject some environment variables and run 2 sh scripts. that's all

Comment: I'm sorry but it isn't that damn simple: explain step by step what are you doing, which steps are invoked, and when you are exactly figuring out that files are missing. There are many ways to remove files from a working-directory and the git-plugin works as expected and has no strange configuration-options.

Comment: seriously, nothing more. all build process is only two steps, both call shell scripts. I'm figuring out that files are missing in those scripts, by printing 'ls' on workspace dir, before doing anything

Comment: sorry for being that demanding - i might have been that f.e. an `ant`-task or anything else may have cleaned the working-directory before the build.

Comment: Nope, I don't use ant. I build php projects mostly with some shell scripts and Docker (pull code with git, inject env variables, run shell scripts). And in very beginning I get workspace without dot-files. Mystery =(( I don't know what is underlying jenkins, maybe it creates workspace with ant or sort of. But this is absolutely annoying..

Comment: Oooooh CRAP! I was absolutely wrong =((( Dotfiles are in place, I've used 'ls' instead of 'ls -A' and didn't see them in output. But they are really cutting during deploy and it seems that problem is with zipping. I use "cd $this->workspace && zip -q -r $targetZip * -x .git*" command and it seems to ignore all dotfiles... What a shame (

Comment: changed 'zip' to 'git archive'... works like a charm. Sorry for time wasting =(

Comment: You're welcome - glad everything led to a solution.. :D